# How to hide email account password in PHP code running in HTML file?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, phpmailer

I edited the .htaccess file on my website and enabled PHP code to run in HTML files.

It was all working just fine, but somehow the .htaccess file got changed back on the server, and HTML was removed from the PHP handler list.

This not only broke functionality on the website but when viewing the source code of the Contact page you can see the email account password, which I added to the PHP code for PHP Mailer which is used for the contact form.

How can I protect the password, in case something like this happens again? I'm relatively new to PHP and wondering if there's any clever way to do this, like perhaps pulling in the password from an external file only if PHP is running correctly?

Comment: show us please the php code as an example. Maybe your provider updated the PHP version and [short_open_tag](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) is disabled

Comment: dont rely on .html files being handled by php. make sure all your files are .php and use server rewrites if you insist on having .html at the end.

Comment: Why do you need to store the password in your PHP script in the first place?

Comment: @Systix, I don't believe that short_open_tag was disabled as I'm using <?php ?> and it's working.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, besides the security risk I encountered, are there other issues with HTML files being handled by PHP?

Comment: @KoalaYeung, when I downloaded PHPMailer there was an example page and it requires entering my SMTP details including password:
$mail->Password
$success=smtpmailer($to, $email, $first_name." ".$last_name ,$Subject, $Body);
Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, keeping secrets in an external file is what you need. As others have mentioned, it's also important to keep this file outside of your web root, so that there is no direct URL that points at it. In PHP the most popular way to do this is to use [dotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv). The idea is that you store all your secrets in a `.env` file in the root of your project, but you ensure that this file is **not** saved in your git repo, most often by making sure your `.gitignore` file excludes it. So you might end up with a structure like this:

```
/var/www/my_site <- your project root on your server
    app/ <- project files
    vendor/ <- dependencies
    public/ <- web root
        index.php <- default entry point for your app
    .env <- config and secrets, note is *outside* web root
```

Your `.env` file will look like this:

```
EMAIL_USERNAME = me@example.com
EMAIL_PASSWORD = supersecret
```

To get at those values, you use dotenv's `env()` global function like this:

```
$mail->Username = env('EMAIL_USERNAME');
$mail->Password = env('EMAIL_PASSWORD');
```

You can of course use this for many things, such as database credentials, auth keys for external services, your app's name, etc.

It's very common to include a file in your git repo (usually called something like `.env.dist` or `example.env`) that contains the structure and variable names that you use in your real `.env` file without actually including the secrets themselves, just:

```
EMAIL_USERNAME =
EMAIL_PASSWORD =
```

This makes it easy to see what values you need to fill in if your'e doing a fresh install.

Other things you want to do to protect your secrets:

- Configure your web server to refuse to serve any filename ending with `.env`
- Ensure that all debug output is disabled in production (e.g. if you did a `var_dump($mail)`, it would reveal your email password)

There are other ways of keeping secrets outside your app, such as via real system environment variables, but dotenv is probably all you need.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I've been trying this but I'm stuck. I'm quite new to PHP and I'm not using a git repo. I've just created the PHP files for my website using Visual Studio Code, and upload them to my shared hosting space by ftp.

I asked the hosting company to install phpdotenv which they have done, and I can see a subfolder vendor\vlucas\phpdotenv . My hosting space has the structure: Home/public_html/mysite.com/ , and I created a file called ".env" in the Home folder and inserted these lines:
EMAIL_USERNAME = me@example.com
EMAIL_PASSWORD = supersecret

Comment: And then I created a PHP file: Home/public_html/mysite.com/test-env.php and put this code in it:
<?php
$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();
$myemailuser = $_ENV['EMAIL_USERNAME'];
print_r($myemailuser);
?>

But it's giving an internal server error. In the PHP file, VSCode has underlined the text "Dotenv\Dotenv" on the 2nd line, saying "undefined type".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is really a separate question. You don’t have to use git, but that doesn’t stop you using composer. Run it locally and upload `vendor` with your other files. Get values via dotenv’s `env()` function, not from `$_ENV`. VS Code will have a composer plugin to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Keep file with the password in it **outside** of the document root.

Then `include()` it.

Comment: What do you mean "outside of the document root"? The Contact page is in the root of the website "mysite.com". So where would I place the file to be included?

Comment: this is good advice as long as no *open_basedir restriction in effect.* on shared hosting.

Comment: Can you please explain this as I don't understand. Also, should I store part of the PHP code with my SMTP settings in a .php file or should I just store the password in a text file?

Comment: Most hosters have the root of your domain set up to point into a directory called `public_html` or something similar (that’s called the document root), but you have access to a folder level above that - that would be “outside the document root”.